# slideToggle() not showing the child of one class

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

sorry if this seems like a bit of a redundant question, I have found answers that seem to solve it in theory though in practice I cant seem to find out why it isn't working.

I am trying to slideToggle() the child of a class using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".ansArray").toggle();

    $(".resultName").click(function(){
        $(".ansArray", this).slideToggle(100);
    });
});
```

However for some reason, when I refresh my page and click on the ".resultName" class, nothing happens, no error logged in the console either (ctrl+shift+j).

If I do th following code.....I get (as expected) all items within the class "ansArray" will show....I only want the "ansArray" child of the clicked "resultName" if you know what I mean.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".ansArray").toggle();

    $(".resultName").click(function(){
        $(".ansArray").slideToggle(100);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance guys!!

Comment: What's your HTML code? Please [edit] that in.

Comment: It means that `.ansArray` is not a descendant of the `.resultName`.

Comment: Sorry @Scimonster its not letting me get the HTML in, but on further inspection, since I had it generated by php, I just missed that and the "ansArray" wasn't made a child of "resultName", Thanks a million! sorry about that!